# Kafka: Scala to Python conversion

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Reference to : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#consumerstrategies

Is there is python version of this example? Reference only has java equivalent.  I found some similarities at https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaProducer.html.

I can match bootstrap.servers to bootstrap_servers , key.serializer to key_serializer ,  value.serializer to value_serializer, but I can't match the last 3, "group.id",  "auto.offset.reset" and
  "enable.auto.commit".

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics = Array("topicA", "topicB")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)

stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Scala code you're looking at is for a Consumer. So you need to check the Consumer settings not the Producer's.

If you look at https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html you can find their equivalent:

- `group.id`: `group_id`
- `auto.offset.reset`: `auto_offset_reset`
- `enable.auto.commit`: `enable_auto_commit`

Also note that the Consumer has deserializers not serializers, so:

- `key.deserializer`: `key_deserializer`
- `value.deserializer`: `value_deserializer`

Answer (score 0):

> I found some similarities at https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io

That isn't Spark code, though. Spark would require the Properties of the Java Kafka API.

[`spark-streaming-kafka-0-10` is not available in Python](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/streaming-kafka-integration.html), but if you want to use Spark, this is the 0.8 API, [which has Python examples](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html)

```
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

# ssc = <get a StreamingContext>
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic], {"metadata.broker.list": brokers})
```